# Modifying the size of image taken by a camera in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take an image of specified dimensions and saving it in a desired location on the SD card. I am using intent.putExtra to take the image via the  default camera application.

Here goes the code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Setting up the URI for the desired location
    imageFile = "bmp"+v.getId()+".png";
    File f = new File (folder,imageFile);
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

    //Setting the desired size parameters
    private Camera mCamera;      
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);       

    //Passing intent.PutExtras to defaul camera activity
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(i,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);   
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    return;
}
```

The camera activiy force closes after taking an image.
Is it possible to modify the size of the images taken by the default camera activity in this way??

Or A separate camera application is necessary??

Comment: We can't figure out why there's a problem if you don't tell us what the problem *is*.

Comment: I have edited the question , please have a look

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full logs from the force close? And, if you're able to read them, highlighting that part of the code would be useful also.

Comment: The problem is I am unable to use USB debugging due to some reasons, so unable to acheive the logcat.

Comment: Then you'll have to comment out line-by-line to find the issue, or find some way to USB debug it. (There really shouldn't be any reason you can't plug the phone into your machine.)

Answer (score 0):

If your image is saved as a file, create a bitmap from that file and decrease its size using this method and pass this bitmap to your Activity:

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int requiredSize) {
    try {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize
                    || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null,
                o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```